# UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT ERROR

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

While I am using my sandbox credential with test card my code is working fine and response.Status is coming as "approved" but when I try live credential with my real card its throwing "UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT" error. 
This is the error I got:
{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"c446507b37b6c"}\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors\",\"debug_id\":\"c0d38fae9eade\"}"

The difference between my sandbox account and live accounts are,
[image]

Someone please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. It is not said load enough while playing with the sandbox, although Paypal knows exactly my Locality.
Anyway, only US and UK developer can use REST API for vaulted credit cards payments.
From that link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions
"The REST API supports a number of countries and currencies. The REST API provides simple payment processing for common business needs, including PayPal payments, direct credit card payments, authorization and capture, and refunds. For more advanced payment solutions such as parallel and recurring payments, you can use the NVP/SOAP APIs."